Merge Rows using SQL Server Block
I have a table like below, I want to merge it as below using a function or procedure or a block by passing two values eg. 101,102
If the ident and val are same for two different IDs ignore that rec during merge, closedate can be get sysdate or getdate in case of terming them out.
All the records in 102 will be termed out except which has Ident and val same, in this case we ignore that record. Also find the create table script in code.



ID
Ident
source
val
opendate
closedate
IsActive




101
euid01
File01
x010
01-01-2023
01-01-2999
1


101
euid02
File01
x111
01-01-2023
01-01-2999
1


101
euid02
File01
x222
01-01-2023
01-10-2024
0


102
euid01
File11
x010
01-01-2023
01-01-2999
1


102
euid02
File12
x333
01-01-2023
01-01-2999
1


102
euid02
File10
x444
01-01-2023
01-10-2024
0



Output as below



ID
Ident
source
val
opendate
closedate
IsActive




101
euid01
File01
x010
01-01-2023
01-01-2999
1


101
euid02
File01
x111
01-01-2023
01-01-2999
1


101
euid02
File01
x222
01-01-2023
01-10-2024
0


101
euid02
File12
x333
01-01-2023
22-10-2024
0


101
euid02
File10
x444
01-01-2023
22-10-2024
0



CREATE TABLE MDM 
(
    ID        INT,
    Ident     VARCHAR(20),
    source    VARCHAR(20),
    val       VARCHAR(20),
    opendate  DATETIME,
    closedate DATETIME,
    Isactive  BIT
)

INSERT INTO MDM (ID, Ident, source, val, opendate, closedate, Isactive) 
VALUES (101, 'euid01' ,'File01', 'x010', '01-01-2023', '01-01-2999', 1),
       (101, 'euid02' ,'File01', 'x111', '01-01-2023', '01-01-2999', 1),
       (101, 'euid02' ,'File01', 'x222', '01-01-2023', '01-10-2024', 0),
       (102, 'euid01' ,'File01', 'x010', '01-01-2023', '01-01-2999', 1),
       (102, 'euid02' ,'File02', 'x333', '01-01-2023', '01-01-2999', 1),
       (102, 'euid02' ,'File10', 'x444', '01-01-2023', '01-10-2024', 0)

I tried using merge
PROCEDURE merge_by_id (@id_from INT, @id_to INT) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vFrom INT = @id_from
    DECLARE @vInto INT = @id_to

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID,identifier, source, val, opendate) AS rowid, 
            ID, identifier, source, val, opendate, closedate, isActive     
        FROM 
            MDM
    )
    --SELECT * FROM CTE;
    MERGE INTO CTE t
    USING (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID,identifier, source, val, opendate) AS rw, identifier, source, val, opendate, 
       CASE WHEN (identifier,val) IN (SELECT identifier,val FROM MDM WHERE id = @vInto) THEN 1 END AS delete_flag 
      FROM MDM WHERE id = @vFrom) s
    ON (t.rowid = s.rw)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE SET id = @vInto, closedate = getdate(), isActive = 0
        DELETE WHERE delete_flag = 1;
END


A column called "ID" that isn't actually an ID (as it's not unique in the table) is a poor choice of a column named "ID"; does your table not actually have an ID column/Primary Key?

I don't understand the question - is your code not working? are you receiving an error? is the update not happening?

One method seems to be that you could UPDATE all the rows with the unwanted ID (102 in this case) to the wanted ID (101). Then you use a CTE to delete the duplicate rows:
--Probably should use a transaction
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @FromId int = 102, --Unwanted ID
        @ToID int = 101; --Wanted ID

--Update to all the same ID
UPDATE MDM
SET ID = @ToID
FROM dbo.MDM
WHERE MDM.ID = @FromId;

--Delete duplicate rows
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Ident, source, val, opendate, closedate, isactive ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM dbo.MDM
    WHERE ID = @ToID)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;

COMMIT;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MDM;

db<>fiddle
